# How to change default shell of xcode to bash

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, bash, shell

I came across this issue during OClint integration with xcode. 
so OS X 10.2 onwards, it has bash as default shell so whenever you install something and set PATH variables it sets in bash shell. 
Now in xcode for any target if you trying to add a run script in build phase(inside build setting) then it try to run in sh shell so even if you are changing shell path in build phase setting as /bin/bash it always runs as /bin/sh and PATH variables over there are not set so it doesn't find installed oclint.

I try to add path in sh through terminal but may be those path were added for that session only so still give the same error.

> oclint not found, analyzing stopped
>   Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Comment: did you try #!/bin/bash or #!/usr/bin/env bash. oclint's path should be in $PATH and export PATH=..pathforoclint..:$PATH

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** You either change it from Xcode Window by going to your `Project Target > Build Phases > Run Script > Shell` and choose to put in the input text field over there something like `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh`

**Option 2:** Or you can change it from the project.pbxproj file, open it with an editor, it will be under `<Your_App>.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` and update the `shellPath` value where you see something like:

```
 /* Run Script */ = {
                isa = PBXShellScriptBuildPhase;
                buildActionMask = 3117423647;
                files = (
                );
                inputPaths = (
                );
                name = "Run Script";
                outputPaths = (
                );
                runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing = 0;
                shellPath = /bin/bash;
                shellScript = "
```

Comment: Project Target/Build Phases only contains entries for Compile Sources, Link Binary with Libraries and Copy Bundle Resources  in Xcode 12.3 on Catalina for a Swift 5 project targeting iPhone and iPad, iOS12.1 . There is no Run Script entry. File <My_App>.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj does not contain a Run Script section.

Answer (score -1):

If you really need bash instead of sh, if you have to, you could "mv /bin/sh /bin/sh.orig && ln /bin/bash /bin/sh" as root. Bash is (supposed to be) a superset of the Bourne shell, so it can (should) run anything that sh can.

You can also change the shell for the root user (or other /bin/sh using user) to bash. I've been doing that on OS X for years, and using /bin/bash as the shell for root hasn't caused any problems. On recent versions of OS X you can do "chsh root" to do that.

I think it might be simplest to just create a link to oclint in /usr/bin, e.g., "ln -s /path/to/oclint /usr/bin/oclint".

You could also edit /etc/profile and/or /etc/bashrc to set PATH accordingly.

Comment: I tried changing default shell to sh, installed oclint again as suggested in following page in option 2
http://docs.oclint.org/en/dev/intro/installation.html
and tried integrated with xcode as shown in following link
http://docs.oclint.org/en/dev/guide/xcode.html
but still it is giving following error
oclint not found, analyzing stopped
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1 :(

Comment: replacing the shell on disk is not a good idea and could break system tools.